# Angular UI Grid space between capital letters in header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, user-interface, grid, angular-ui-grid

When I use multiple capital letters in the header cells (e.g. GPRS) they automatically get separated by spaces (G P R S). This gets particularly annoying when I have two words (GPRS Signal is displayed as G P R S Signal) or two acronyms (GPRS EDGE is displayed as G P R S E D G E).
Is this meant to be like this? If so, how can i disable it?

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue with ui-grid v3.0.0-RC.18-e4b2293 - 2015-01-29

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I just found a way around this. In the columnDefs property of your gridOptions add a displayName for the column that contains multiple capital letters. Something like this:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
  columnDefs: [
    { name: 'GPRS', displayName: 'GPRS', field: 'gprsField' }
  ]
};
```

Comment: This has solved my problem: adding a displayName does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Also to answer the "Is this meant to be like this?" part of the question - Yes, this is the default as it allows you to define a multi-word name in your column definition in **[Camel Case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)** and have it be displayed as spaced words in the column header.

Comment: And is there a way to switch this CamelCase function off if you dont need it? All my column names are in CAPS, which causes chaos then. Also I have all my column names with underscores, so if there is a feature for that, thats great.

Comment: @Russell I am unaware of a way to turn this CamelCase functionality off

Comment: Unfortunately, display name enforces CamelCase it seems, so displayName: "Vehicle ID" always shows "Vehicle Id" which is annoying

Comment: great @bbak, but what's' the use of the `name` attribute in this case? can it be removed? does it add a name attribute to the HTML element? I have inspected the generated element and there's no added use for it

Comment: @sisimh I'm not sure if name is totally necessary in this case. I was going off the api docs though which say name is a mandatory attribute that you should always have: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef

Comment: I have dynamic column names, what then ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question: how can I disable it?

I modified the source code.  My application is using a local copy of the file in lib/ui-grid.info-x.x.x/release/ui-grid.js

Search for the function called "readableColumnName" and replace or comment out the following:

```
      return columnName;
  //return columnName.replace(/_+/g, ' ')
    // Replace a completely all-capsed word with a first-letter-capitalized version
    //.replace(/^[A-Z]+$/, function (match) {
    //  return angular.lowercase(angular.uppercase(match.charAt(0)) + match.slice(1));
    //})
    // Capitalize the first letter of words
    //.replace(/([\w\u00C0-\u017F]+)/g, function (match) {
    //  return angular.uppercase(match.charAt(0)) + match.slice(1);
    //})
    // Put a space in between words that have partial capilizations (i.e. 'firstName' becomes 'First Name')
    // .replace(/([A-Z]|[A-Z]\w+)([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
    // .replace(/(\w+?|\w)([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2");
    //.replace(/(\w+?(?=[A-Z]))/g, '$1 ');
```

In other words, just return the columnName, don't do any replacing.

Don't forget to reload your webpage/javascript files before you test that it's working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use display name property in UI-Grid : `displayName: 'CAPITAL WORDS'`

> displayName : Column name that will be shown in the header. If
>   displayName is not provided then one is generated using the name.

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/cslczGMtIMZ3bCS6m652?p=preview)